# Convert short number to byte array java

Tags: java, algorithm, byte, short, bcd

my purpose to read from stream as byte per digit do some logic and write back to binary file

Lets say the representation of data is `0F000200 17000000 07003B00`

so we have method to represent it

```
   InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);

    private static int readShort(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
       return stream.read() + stream.read() * 10;
    }

    // ***** when we read the results ******

    int day = readShort(stream); // => 15
    int month = readShort(stream); //  => 2
    int year_suffix = readShort(stream); // => 23
    int hour = readShort(stream); //  => 0
    int minute = readShort(stream); //  => 7
    int second = readShort(stream); // => 59
```

Now I want to write it back as byte array so I did:

```
   FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file");

    writeShort(stream, day);
    writeShort(stream, month);
    writeShort(stream, year);
    writeShort(stream, hour);
    writeShort(stream, minute);
    writeShort(stream, second);


 private static void writeShort(OutputStream stream, int value) throws IOException {
      stream.write(value % 10);
      stream.write(value / 10);
 }
```

But when I look into output file I see the header is not the same

the value are `05010200 03020000 07000905` instead of ***0F000200 17000000 07003B00***

please suggest ( picture from Hex fiend editor)

[image]

Comment: "representation of data is 0F000200 17000000 07003B00" -- this is not BCD. Is the example wrong, or the description? `readShort` only accidentally handled this data correctly (because every second byte is zero)

Comment: Ok , edited the question. Lets ignore the method names, and assume second byte wont be zero, it will be unsigned

Comment: It seems you're only interested in the high byte (and your interpretation is as if it's a *low* byte), so why don't you just read that instead of reading a short?

Comment: It could be that every byte will represent a digit, now the low byte it is accidentally zero. Even though need to gave same results after write

Comment: So, let's take the first datum. What would it mean for 'day' were the second byte not zero?

Comment: If each byte is meant to represent a decimal digit, there shouldn’t be any bytes with values greater than 0x09 right?

Comment: @Tim Moore  - the max value of each byte can be 255 (as decimal value)

Comment: @g00se I guess the day will be bigger

Comment: If the format was BCD (unpacked version, one digit per byte), then 15 really would be stored as 0501, which you `writeShort` produces. But apparently that is not how the format works, so how *is* it meant to work? If each byte can be max 255, isn't it just a normal short that's stored there, not in any fancy format?

Comment: *@g00se I guess the day will be bigger* Is that meant to be a joke? How can it be bigger than 0XFF or decimal 31 for that matter?

Comment: The data is 3rd party and hard to say right now (will check it tomorrow) , but as I know every 1 byte should represent unsigned number with format ( day, month, year ..) , my question was if I read number this way (stream.read() + stream.read() * 10), how i should write to output in order to have same result (reverse) in editor

Comment: `stream.write(value % 256); stream.write(value / 256);` would reproduce the data that you've shown so far, but that is certainly not BCD, and is not symmetric with `stream.read() + stream.read() * 10` (which does not make sense anyway, given the data that you've shown so far)

Comment: Did it, didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to read and write short values spread over two bytes, little-endian (i.e., least significant byte first), you can modify your code like this (but there probably is a more efficient way):

```
private static int readShort(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    return stream.read() + stream.read() * 256;
}

private static void writeShort(OutputStream stream, int value) throws IOException {
    stream.write(value % 256); // or value & 0xFF
    stream.write(value / 256); // or value >> 8
}
```

The point is, you don't want to read and write a decimal digit (10 possible values) at a time, but a byte (256 possible values) at a time.